# Can I have the same method run its logic on floats and/or Vector2?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class with a method that takes two values, a Current Value and a Target Value. The method does a bunch of math calculations with these and returns a value of the same type that was passed in. It also updates some properties of that same type on the class.

However, right now I have two copies of this method (and each property on the class that gets updated by it), one for floats, and one for Vector2, and I might need more in the future. The logic, though, is the exact same (the operations are identical, basic, and don't care about the types).

Is there a way to make this class not care about what type of value is passed to its methods / has as its properties, as long it is a float or Vector2? I tried the generic route, but seems like you can only compare generics and not add or multiply etc.

I could have two different classes, but again I don't want to have the equations in two places.

```
public float Response { get { return 0.2f; } }
public float Damping { get { return 0.5f; } }
public Vector2 VectorVelocity { get; set; }
public float FloatVelocity { get; set; }

public Vector2 Move(Vector2 current, Vector2 target) 
{   
    Vector2 delta;
    delta = target - current;
    this.VectorVelocity += delta * this.Response;

    current += this.VectorVelocity;
    this.VectorVelocity *= this.Damping;

    return current;
}

public float Move(float current, float target) 
{   
    float delta;
    delta = target - current;
    this.FloatVelocity += delta * this.Response;

    current += this.FloatVelocity;
    this.FloatVelocity *= this.Damping;

    return current;
}
```

Comment: You should use generic types. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-classes

Comment: @PaviełKraskoŭski No, they shouldn't, because there's no way you can make a generic either 2 float parameters or a single Vector2 one

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I see. So, you can make two overloaded methods where one method with Vector2 parameter will call another method with two float parameters.

Comment: @PaviełKraskoŭski That's a much more realistic approach, but I would wait to see some code just to be sure

Comment: thanks for the replies, I have added a stripped down version of what I am trying to do. I really only just want one Velocity property.

Comment: @niksga I think it's reasonable to use generic class in your case.

Comment: Isn't a Vector2 a tuple of two floats? I see the methods are quite similar, but critically different. Specially since they affect different state (one affects `FloatVelocity` and the other `VectorVelocity`...)

Comment: @PaviełKraskoŭski I also think that would be ideal, however I can't use the operators I'm using above to operands of generic types (unless I can, somehow?)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto yes, I could just use the Vector method and only care about, say, the x value, and stick with the two Velocity properties if there's no way to collapse it any further. I really think generics would be the best way to go if there was some sort of constraint I could put on the class where T would implement these operators.

Comment: @PaviełKraskoŭski Generics won't work here because of the operators.  There is no constraint that would allow for them.

Comment: @niksga What about using `dynamic`?

Comment: `dynamic` could work here, though it comes with it's own set of issues, like pushing compile time check to run time and being less efficient in general.  Also the result would be `dynamic` and you'd likely have to do some casting.

Comment: Honestly for 6 lines of code I'd say your best off just sticking with overloads.

Comment: To add to what @juharr just mentioned, I really don't think converting this into `dynamic` would be worth it. I would leave it as is

Comment: @juharr thanks, I thought about dynamic but came to those same conclusions. The code is actually a lot longer than this, I just added a stripped down example of what I am trying to do. I suppose using overloads is what I will have to do.

Comment: Another potential solution would be to create wrapper classes for `float` and `Vector2` that implement some interface that exposes `Add`, `Subtract` and `MultipleByFloat` methods.  Then you could use the interface as the constraint in a generic approach.  But I'm not sure all of that would be worth it.

Comment: Or an approach that passed in delegates that handle the specific operations like `Func<float, float, float> Add` and pass in `(a,b) => a + b`.

Comment: @juharr ah, that's a good idea! I may or may not end up doing just that, but I knew there had to be an alternate approach and a way to get it working with generics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a generic approach that requires you to pass in delegates for the various operations.

```
public T Move<T>(T current, T target, 
    Func<T, T, T> subtract, 
    Func<T, T, T> add,
    Func<T, float, T> multiplyByFloat,
    Action<T> setVelocity,
    Func<T> getVelocity,
    ) 
{   
    T delta = subtract(target, current);
    setVelocity(add(getVelocity(), multiplyByFloat(delta, this.Response));    
    current = add(current, getVelocity());
    setVelocity(multiplyByFloat(getVelocity(), this.Damping);    
    return current;
}
```

Then call it like

```
var result = Move(current, target, 
    (a,b) => a - b, 
    (a,b) => a + b,
    (a,b) => a * b,
    v => this.FloatVelocity = v,
    () => this.FloatVelocity);
```

You could take this approach to keep the forumula in one place and still have overrides that make the specific call for you as having to put in all those delegates each time would be painful.

I'd also like to state that I'm not sure this is worth it for the example given, but if the formula is much more complex and you have 3 or more types you need to handle then maybe this approach could be OK, but as you can see the formula is much harder to read this way IMHO.

Comment: Thanks so much! Even if I do not end up implementing this (as legibility is a factor, as you say), this approach really helps me understand generics and delegates more.